# Get second highest category based on a column in Qlik KPI Chart

Tags: qliksense, qlik-expression

Data:
DEALER_CODE
KEY_ANTRAG_ERROR
KDNR
UB_GES

above is the qlik sense table and want to get syntax of problem statement below:

In a KPI box, need to get the KDNR whose rank is 2, for UB_GES is not equal to 0 (Rank of KDNR needs to be calculated based on count of KDNR). This needs to work on dealer code level. Also if there are 2 KDNRs with the same rank, ranking should be done based on highest UB_GES value.
This needs to be done in the front end. No transformations in the script.

Whenever we select any [AUDIT.DEALER_CODE] it should calculate second highest KDNR for respective selection.

Comment: Maybe you could provide an `Inline[]` statement with example data and the desired result. Because this way not only is the problem hard to picture, one can't show you a solution either.